# How to crop many images with the same sizes to some coordinates?

Tags: windows-7, images, crop

There are many images of the same size. Are there ways to crop all of them to the same coordinates?
Windows 7.

Comment: You should always quote your preferred Operating System in questions like this so that you get the most relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can you imagemagick to do this. Here are some examples from product [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_page):

```
  convert rose:                    rose.gif
  convert rose: -crop 40x30+10+10  crop.gif
  convert rose: -crop 40x30+40+30  crop_br.gif
  convert rose: -crop 40x30-10-10  crop_tl.gif
  convert rose: -crop 90x60-10-10  crop_all.gif
  convert rose: -crop 40x30+90+60  crop_miss.gif
```

And one sample loop can exec it for all the images. Something like:

```
for i in `ls in\`
do
convert $i -crop 40x30+10+10 out/`basename $i`
done
```

Above i assume in files are in directory in/ and out files will be stored in directory out/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows, download the [portable or installer Windows binary releases of ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php), then in the directory with the images run the following command (naturally with *convert.exe* in your PATH somewhere):

```
for %f in (*.jpg) do convert -crop 32x32+16+16 "%~f" "cropped_%~f"
```

There you go, simple as pie. No "UNIX-y shell" or "more than forty lines of code" required as [suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/920580/how-to-crop-many-images-with-the-same-sizes-to-some-coordinates#comment1242319_920591) by some.